# change data capture - monitor single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc

Afternoon all,

I've enabled CDC on a particular table (code below) however I'm wondering if it's possible to track changes on `LocationTypeID column` only, yet record the remaining columns of the row within the system table?

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  
@source_schema = N'LocationManagementOperational',  
@source_name   = N'FunctionalLocation',  
@role_name     = N'Public',  
@captured_column_list = N'[ID], [ParentID], [LocationTypeID], [Path], [Elevation], [InclinationPositionX], [InclinationPositionY], [InclinationPercentage], [InclinationAzimuth], [DispatchSignId], [MaterialGeometry], [DynamicDigLimitInclination], [LastUpdate], [RecordStatus]',
@index_name = N'UQ_FunctionalLocation',
@supports_net_changes = 1
```

Comment: Why it's not possible to track changes on LocationTypeID column only?

Comment: Was hoping to bring through other relevenat fields to avoid having to join additional tables